# Validation on images if passing despite clear failures, why?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am using Laravel 5.7.  I have a form with a file upload on it called `logo`.  My form has the correct `enctype` (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`).

I have the following rules against the `logo` field:

`['required', 'image', 'dimensions:max_width=200,max_height=200']`

If I try to upload something that isn't an image it fails, which is correct.

However, if I try to upload a 3000x3000px jpg this goes through without issue and the file is uploaded.  It's as though my `dimensions` rule is being ignored.

Am I missing something?

Comment: do u use in form multipart data?

Comment: Yes, `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.  My file is uploaded, so that isn't the issue anyway, it's that I'm able to upload images far too large and validation is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your rule, it is as documented, but just in case something's wrong with the parser, have you tried using:

```
'image' => ['required', 'image', Rule::dimensions()->maxWidth(200)->maxHeight(200)]
```

Comment: Still allows me to upload huge images unfortunately

Comment: @Mike which version of Laravel are you using, I just tried your rules on my project and I get the correct error which is: The picture has invalid image dimensions.

Comment: I use the same, all seems fine in my project. Try another image or check if PHP reads the resolution right by printing out the size`dd(getimagesize(request()->file('image')));` the first two items of the array are the resolution.

Comment: @mike have you tried debugging what I've said above this comment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use another format of validation like that:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'image'=> 'required|image|dimensions:min_width=200,min_height=200',
]);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Still allows me to upload huge images, must be something else